# Display info. from a mySQL database to a webpage using nodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, promise

This is my first question to Stackoverflow, and I hope I word it properly. I have two files, one that connects to the database, db.js, and one that acts as the server, server.js. I want to display the information from the database on a webpage, but I keep getting a blank page. I am, however, able to console.log the information. I'm guessing it is a problem with how I am returning the result, but I've tried various options and nothing seems to work. Here is the latest working code.

```
db.js file

function getCaughtData () {


return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : 'password',
database : 'database'
});
connection.connect(function(err){ 
connection.query("SELECT * FROM caughtInfo", function (err, result)       {
        if (err) throw err;
        // console.log("calling inside the function", result);
        resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
    })}

)});
}
function getEmails(){
getCaughtData().then(result => {console.log(result)});
};


server.js file

app.get('/database', (req, res) => {
res.send(db.getEmails())        
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I should have tried a little longer before posting this question. Here's the code that was used to solve my problem above:

db.js

```
function getCaughtData () {


return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : 'password',
database : 'database'
});;
    connection.connect(function(err){ 
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM caughtInfo", function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // console.log("calling inside the function", result);
        resolve(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
    })}

)});
}
```

server.js

```
app.get('/snow/dog', (req, res) => {
db.getCaughtData().then(result => {res.send(result)});    
})
```